# Python pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am working through the book "Python for Data Analysis", but it seems half of the code runs into small errors. I have switched from Anaconda to Enthought for installation purposes. Currently only into page 31 I can't get this error fixed, yet the dataframe data is visible.

```
mean_ratings =data.pivot_table('rating',rows='title',cols='gender',aggfunc='mean')
```

---

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e71d4eca7ef3> in <module>()
      1 mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', rows='title',
----> 2 cols='gender', aggfunc='mean')

TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'
```

Comment: use `values` instead of `rows`

Comment: That book as good as it is, is very out of date now, there will be a second edition coming at some point: https://twitter.com/wesmckinn/status/715320179173888001?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw, the error stems from a rationalisation of the param naming in the various methods, so the param naming is more consistent now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mean_ratings = data.pivot_table(values='rating', index='title',
                                columns='gender', aggfunc='mean')
```

As @unutbu has mentioned in the comment, very old versions of [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) (<=0.13) used `rows` instead of the `index` parameter.

Comment: @unutbu, thank you! it took me some time to find the old version using `rows` parameters

Comment: Thank you. Yes I agree. I find myself using google to fix everything the book has been replaced by.